# Need to call a method when users closes tab

Tags: reactjs

From few days I am facing a challenge. I want to call a method when user close a tab or window, so before closing the tab I want to execute a method. I am working in functional component ReactJS. It will be very helpful if get some solution regarding my query. I am placing my logout method inside that but it  is getting triggered multiple times ?

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => 
{
ev.preventDefault();
onLogOut();
return ev.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to close?' ;
});
```

I need to implement the onLogOut

But the way I am using it the logout method is triggered multiple times. Any  solution to make it call only once ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React, please consider implementing such code in useEffect with a clean up function, for more information about [clean up function in react](https://hackernoon.com/cleanup-functions-in-reacts-useeffect-hook-explained)

```
useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => { ev.preventDefault(); __onLogOut(); return ev.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to close?'; }); 
return() => {
 window.removeEventListener('beforeunload')
}
},[])
```

Comment: Yes done this 
       useEffect(() => {
         window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => 
         {  
           ev.preventDefault();
           __onLogOut();
           return ev.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to close?';
         });
     }, []);

For the first time only one time it is getting called but from next onwards on same tab logout API is getting added means calling twice next time calling thrice.

Comment: @SauravChakraborty For every `addEventListener` you have to have `removeEventListener`. See a tutorial on ` useEffect`.

Comment: @cloud-dev this is more of comment than an answer. You should either expand your answer or put it as a comment instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).